# CSS Transform-Origin and image alignment

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to rotate an image when i hover over a div using Rotate and Transform-Origin. It was works when the image is centered in the div but when i change the vertical position of the image and make the relevant changes to the Transform-origin values the image still rotates but is slightly off center.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

jsfiddle here (only seems to work in firefox)

http://jsfiddle.net/boyle/U3yLk/

html

```
<div class="box">
<div class="c">
<img class="pic" src="p.png"/>
</div>
```

css

```
.box{
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
background-color: #4781AA;
display:block;
}   
.c{
width:200px;
height:300px;
display:block;
transition: all 1s ease;
}
.c:hover{
transform: rotate(180deg);
transform-origin: 100px 150px;  
}
.pic {
position: relative;
left:50px;
top: 100px;
}
```

This also only seems to work in Firefox!

Cheers

Comment: `transform` is still requires a prefix in Chrome AFAIK

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes it does.  webkit friendly version: http://jsfiddle.net/U3yLk/5/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.transform{
 transform:rotate(60deg);
 -ms-transform:rotate(60deg);
 -moz-transform:rotate(60deg);
 -webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);
 -o-transform:rotate(60deg);
 }
```